# Cannot cast xmlReader to Parser

Tags: java, xml, casting, compiler-errors, sax

I'm trying to parse XML file with SAX following [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) tutorial on Maven project. Here's my `SAXLocalNameCount`:

```
 public class SAXLocalNameCount extends DefaultHandler {
        private static String filename = ".\\file.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, org.xml.sax.SAXException, IOException, SAXException {

    SAXParserFactory spfactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spfactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        SAXParser saxParser = spfactory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
        xmlReader.setContentHandler(new SAXLocalNameCount());
        xmlReader.parse(convertToFileURL());

    }

    private static void usage() {
        System.err.println("Usage: SAXLocalNameCount <file.xml>");
        System.err.println(" -usage or -help = this message");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    private Hashtable tags;

    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        tags = new Hashtable();
    }

    public void startElement(String namespaceURI,
                             String localName,
                             String qName,
                             Attributes atts)
            throws SAXException {

        String key = localName;
        Object value = tags.get(key);

        if (value == null) {
            tags.put(key, new Integer(1));
        }
        else {
            int count = ((Integer)value).intValue();
            count++;
            tags.put(key, new Integer(count));
        }
    }

    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        Enumeration e = tags.keys();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String tag = (String) e.nextElement();
            int count = (Integer) tags.get(tag);
            System.out.println("Local Name \"" + tag + "\" occurs "
                    + count + " times");
        }
    }
    private static String convertToFileURL() {
        String path = new File(filename).getAbsolutePath();
        if (File.separatorChar != '/') {
            path = path.replace(File.separatorChar, '/');
        }

        if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
            path = "/" + path;
        }
        return "file:" + path;
    }

}
```

This line:

```
XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
```

gives me error:

ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser cannot be cast to jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.XMLReader

What am I missing here?

Comment: The line of code you mention does not appear in the tutorial you mention. Unclear why you think this should ever work. You can't just make it up as you go along.

Comment: @EJP No wonder I've got downvotes. Thanks, I edited it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I was importing from **jdk.internal.org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler** and the right import was supposed to be **org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler**